# Flash Projector fullscreen on video

Tags: flash, video, fullscreen, projector

I'm setting a fullscreen in a Projector flash using:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Next I load a video (flv with a swf player) and I add in a "container" movieclip called "windowSmall" using:

```
loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(path_to_swf));
windowSmall.addChild(gallery);
```

After I add the video to windowSmall,
the video instead of been displayed in the window is took to fullscreen.
Then I have to press ESC to exit the fullscreen mode of the video (and the projector lose his fullscreen too).

Anyone know why the loaded video is opened in fullscreen and how to avoid it?
I want the the projector is fullscreen, but the loaded video will be simply as his original dimensions inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: you have to add

```
istanceNameOfFLVPlayback.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

inside the swf that has the FLV and the FLVPlayback